# Minecraft: Is there a way to activate command blocks even if you're not within range?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a unique skywars in vanilla minecraft by using command blocks, but the (clone) command I'm using to reset the map will only activate when someone is within range.  For example if I use the command (`setblock x y z redstone_block`) to run the clone command, I have to be within a certain distance for the clone to actually do its intended job.  For a normal map, "spawn chunks" would work, but I have made my skywars in the end so the players would immediately fall to their deaths.

**Is there a way to activate the command after the game is finished and no one is still near the command blocks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [spawn chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk) for this.

> The spawn chunks usually consist of an area of 16×16 chunks centered as close as possible to the world spawn point.

You can change the spawn point of the world, and thus the location of the spawn chunks by using `/setworldspawn`.